# Function compiles and works on some data but not on others?

Tags: delphi, freepascal, lazarus

Part of my program reads ASCII text from a buffer of type char, which itself can contain some non-printable non-ASCII garbage. When such areas are displayed, such as in `ShowMessage(strVar)`, if there are null characters (`0x00`), the string is not displayed, even if there is printable text in it.

So I wrote this small function (I am trying to get into the habit of writing functions for these tricks but still not very good at it) to clean the variable of any non-printable null chars :

```
// FUNCTION RemoveNullChars : Removes 0x00 from strings, which cause empty string
// fields if not removed sometimes

function TForm1.RemoveNullChars(strValue: string): String;
var
  i : integer;
  NullChar : char;

begin
  NullChar := Chr($00);
  for i := 0 to Length(strValue) do
    begin
    if strValue[i] = NullChar then
      strValue[i] := ' ';
    end;
result := strValue;
end;
```

It compiles OK, and actually works on some buffer segments...it does actually strip out the spaces fine, but not ALWAYS. Other times, with a different data sources (but the time kind of data source), I get this error :

[image]

I can't work out why it compiles OK and actually works OK on some data but not on others?

Comment: Please don't put tag information in your title. The tagging system here is very good at classifying things, and doesn't need help. :-) Please see [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/172661). Thanks.

Comment: Look at the library StringReplace function (http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=StringReplace)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Pascal, strings are one-indexed, not zero-indexed, so your `for` loop should be starting at 1.

If you're getting a `SIGSEGV` error, that's the *nix equivalent of an Access Violation. (It's a bit strange to see that message in a Windows-style dialog box!)  What it means is usually that you're dereferencing a null pointer.

If I had to guess, I'd say you were running this routine on an empty string, which is represented internally as a null pointer.  Because the length of the string is 0, and you're erroneously looping from 0 to length instead of 1 to length, it tries to dereference the string pointer and retrieve element 0 of the array, and you get this error.